# Can I deploy fulfillment in my own server with Actions SDK?

Tags: actions-on-google

I'm a beginner, and I can't understand something about building fulfillment with the Node.js client library (Actions SDK). The development document use the Actions SDK by firebase, but I don't want to deploy fulfillment by firebase.

So I don't know how to deploy fulfillment in my own server with Actions SDK. Please tell me how to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one working example with nodeJs library

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var exps = express();

const ApiAiApp = require('actions-on-google').ApiAiApp;

exps.use(bodyParser.json());

// API.AI actions
const WELCOME_ACTION = 'input.welcome';

exps.post('/hook', function(request, response) {
  const app = new ApiAiApp({request, response});
  function greetUser (app) {
    app.tell("Hello World!");
  }

  let actionMap = new Map();
  actionMap.set(WELCOME_ACTION, greetUser);

  app.handleRequest(actionMap);
});

exps.listen((process.env.PORT || 7001), function() {
    console.log("App up and running, listening.")
})
```

above example will return "Hello World"

You also need to keep in mind that api.ai & actions-on-google only accept https fulfillment. Without SSL you won't be able to connect to your webhook.

Comment: Thank you! Although I want to creating a Smart Home App (Smart Home apps is not supported in API.AI), but your example was very helpful to me. And if you have some example about ActionsSdkApp, it will be more helpful. Thanks again.

Comment: I think this link can help you 
[actions-on-google-smartHome](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/)