# How to create my own DialogFlow fulfillment web hook using the "dialogFlow" module of the actions-on-google package?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm developing an Action for Google Actions and I'm using DialogFlow to process the user's speech as intents. These intents are currently fulfilled by a Node.js web hook hosted as a Google Cloud Function (i.e. Firebase). However, due to new requirements, the web hook must now be moved from Firebase to the client's server.

So, my question is: how can I adapt the web hook to run on a server other than Firebase?

Below is the current (simplified) code for the web hook. The fulfillments of all intents are relatively simple, so this web hook is heavily based on [Google's sample code](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/actions-2/index.html).

```
'use strict';

const {
  dialogflow,
  Suggestions
} = require('actions-on-google');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const app = dialogflow({debug: true});

app.intent('Default Fallback Intent', (conv) => {
    conv.ask('Please repeat');
});

app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', (conv) => {
    conv.ask('Hi, what do you wanna talk about?');
    conv.ask(new Suggestions(['fashion tips', 'celebrity news']));
});

// handlers for other intents...

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

I would like to keep as much of the current code (which uses the `dialogFlow`, `Suggestions` and others modules of the `actions-on-google` package) as possible in the adaptation, as the action has a large number of intents fulfilled by the web hook.

Another way to think about the question is: assuming the web hook is served using express or http, how can I make the above app object process requests? And how can write the responses?

I could not find any example, tutorial or question on this particular issue. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45807482/can-i-deploy-fulfillment-in-my-own-server-with-actions-sdk) question is similar, but the author does not use DialogFlow, as is my case. Google's documentation also seem a little sparse in this regard, focusing on serving the web hook as a Google Cloud Function.

In the above code, I tried replacing the last line (`exports.dialogFlow...`) for the following bits:

```
const express = require('express');
const server = express();
server.post('/hook', app);
server.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server listening on port 3000.'))
```

However, when manually executing a POST request to the web hook using the JSON displayed in the simulator's "Request" tab, the error "TypeError: Can not convert undefined or null to object" occurs, which makes me think that some header or some attribute in the request body is missing.

Am I missing something? I feel I may have skipped a guide or two, but can not seem to find them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pretty close. The part you're missing is that you need to use the `body-parser` middleware to generate the `body` attribute of the request, which will contain the body after parsing it as JSON.

Your code might look something like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const server = express();
server.use(bodyParser.json());
server.post('/hook', app);
server.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server listening on port 3000.'))
```

Comment: Thank you. I have not had yet the opportunity to test the solution. But I will surely use it.